# ImageView inside ConstraintLayout does not work

Tags: android, xml, layout, android-constraintlayout

I have a problem with correct display of ImageView. I want to display ImageView inside ConstraintLayout. On preview it looks exactly as i need, but when i'm starting it on device it looks completly dirrerent. This layout is places inside recycle view. What is wrong with this code?

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/promotionRow"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
android:background="#fff"
android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
android:layout_marginRight="10dp">
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/promotionImageLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintHeight_default="spread"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/promotionImageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_start_promotion"
        android:background="@mipmap/ic_start_promotion"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_min="150dp" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/fadeGradientImageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:background="@drawable/fade_image_background" />
    <TextView
        android:text="Sample title"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:id="@+id/promotionNameTextView"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/promotionDescriptionTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="13sp"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
    android:text="Sampe description" />
</LinearLayout>
```

EDIT: Deep explanation:

I want to create row for RecycleView. Each row have to contains image, title and description. Title have to be in the left bottom corner of the image. Description have to be below the image. After that i have to put gradient (black in the bottom) into the image. Screen with "Preview" is exactly what i need.

**EDIT2: Everything with this layout is ok. It is working as expected, i forget that i made some changes in kotlin code... Sory for problem.**

Comment: why used linear layout inside ConstraintLayout because ConstraintLayout is provide linear and relative layout both features.

Comment: I think you have to use framelayout for this kind of scenario

Answer (score 5):

First things first, every view should apply the attribute rules of its parent `ViewGroup`. ConstraintLayout doesn't support `match_parent`. It supports the `0dp` value which means "match constraint". This way the view will expand to fill the constraint bounded space.

Next, ConstraintLayout was created to achieve a flat view hierarchy for better layout performance. So, never nest it inside a LinearLayout as it has the chains feature to get the same behavior in a more flexible way. Plus, you can achieve the structure with a ConstraintLayout at the top level .

Another thing, If you are going to define the same margin in all directions, you can just use `layout_margin`.

Finally, you have [overdraw](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/inspect-gpu-rendering) problems. ConstraintLayout is flexible enough to allow us to position views as backgrounds and help us avoid overlapped backgrounds.

Here's a solution:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/promotionRow"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/promotion_image"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/promotion_image"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_start_promotion"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_min="150dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/shadow"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="@drawable/fade_image_background"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/promotion_image"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/promotion_name"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:text="Sample title"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/promotion_image"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/description"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:padding="12dp"
        android:text="Sampe description"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/promotion_image" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Try it. Hope this helps!

Comment: This answer really helped me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, trying to write more presicely what do you want? Display image view inside layout it's somthing common words. As for your code, beside you don't have any constraints. You have strange view height, for second ImageView:

```
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

It may overlay all other children view, it's very strange parameter.

Comment: I places this parameter because i want to display first ImageView (this image should determine layout height)  and then put on it another ImageView with gradient mask.

Comment: Ok, then as I say describe more precicely what do you want? And what a problem? I can't understand it from your post, sorry

Comment: Edited first post, is it enough or i should write more?