# Why does ImageView show a generic image in Android Studio instead of the requested image, which works on the device?

Tags: android-studio, imageview

The relevant xml code:

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="409dp"
        android:layout_height="579dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/title_top"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/title_bottom"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="1dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent"
            android:src="@drawable/elenas_shepherd"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            android:contentDescription="@string/splash_description"
            />

    </LinearLayout>
```

(I've only included the inner layout and the ImageView; I can include more if need be.)

The image "elenas_shepherd" looks like a shepherd. However, Android Studio's layout tool shows this, instead:

[image: generic image]

**Why doesn't the correct image show in Android Studio?**

That looks like a generic image. The image shows up fine on the device, but overflows its parent. I don't understand that, either, but I'm reasonably sure I can fix the overflow if I can first convince Android Studio to show the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You see those blue boxes in the upper left hand corner of the screenshot? Click on those. You'll see the options "Design", "Blueprint", and "Design + Blueprint". You've selected "Blueprint", but you want "Design." Switching over gets you this:

[image]

Alas, the preview does not overflow here, so I have to figure out my problem a different way.

Comment: PS The problem with the overflow is due to the parent layout not respecting `match_parent`. See [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51767791/imageview-inside-constraintlayout-does-not-work) for details on that. It doesn't show up in the Layout Editor because the virtual device's dimensions are enough to show the image at full resolution; the actual device's dimensions were too small.